Is it possible to have chart on NDX which closes at 4PM EST & have indicator on NDX chart that fetches data from NQ1! overnight & plots levels on NDX
Is it possible to have chart on NDX which closes at 4PM EST but have an indicator on the NDX chart that will still fetch data from NQ1! futures overnight session while NDX is closed and after an internal computation by the indicator will plot lines (or at least display table values) on the NDX chart during the overnight session?
It appears Tradingview it will only fetch data from a different symbol that the chart is on only during the hours that both symbols are open - in this example meaning if the chart is on NDX which only trades from 9:30AM EST to 4:00PM EST --that it will only allow you to fetch data from NQ1! Futures (while the chart is on NDX) during the hours that NDX and NQ1! are both open--so the fetching of the data from NQ1! stops at 4:00 PM EST when NDX closes even though NQ1! continues to trade in extended hours and overnight and before 930AM the next day.  Is there any work-around?NDX CHART

You can use session.ismarket, session.ispremarket or session.ispostmarket

Stackoverflow is not a coding service. To get an answer, you must share your code. What you tried, or reproduce the unexpected behavior.
